# how to run this node.js when i click this button

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
/*socket.js*/
var net = require('net');

var ip = '127.0.0.1';
var port = 7000;

var socket = new net.Socket();
socket.connect({host:ip, port:port}, function() {
   console.log('connected');
   socket.write('1');
   socket.end();
});
```

```
/*home.js*/
function Home(){
    const emitOpen=(e)=>{
        e.preventdefault();
        /*i want to run that code*/
    }
    return (
        <div className="center">  
              <Button color="secondary" onClick={emitOpen}>blabla</Button>
        </div>
    );
  
}
```

i want to run socket.js to send imformation by tcp when i click the button on home.js.

home.js is base on react.

Comment: Manually creating sockets isn't considered a good practice; Instead check out [`socket.io`](https://socket.io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is about how to implementation invoke/call a function(which trigger socket), so consider these steps:

1. you need a **button** with an action
2. your action will be calling an **API**
3. this **API** can be `GET or POST` as they similar for this job
4. implement your **API** endpoint on your `node` application
5. connect your **socket** on this endpoint, so whenever the user presses the button, this endpoint will call and trigger to connect the socket connection.
6. similarly you can create another API to **close** your socket connection.

hope to useful.